# How to change the concurrency type for Core Data in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

When you create a SwiftUI core data app, nowadays, Xcode creates this struct.

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
  static let shared = PersistenceController()
  
  static var preview: PersistenceController = {
    let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
    let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
    return result
  }()
  
  var context:NSManagedObjectContext {
    return container.viewContext
  }
  
  var container: NSPersistentContainer
  
  init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
  
    
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "PharmaTrac")
    container.newBackgroundContext()

    if inMemory {
      container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {(storeDescription, error) in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        
        /*
         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
         * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
         * The device is out of space.
         * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
         */
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I want to change the context concurrency type to private queue, like in this

```
var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
```

But this way apple creates it, the context is created automatically.

How do I create a context with `.privateQueueConcurrencyType`?

Comment: I think you could create you own core data stack, and pass your custom context in the environment.

Comment: You will always need a context for the main thread so you should not try to change the default one, the easiest way forward is to add a method in PersistenceController that creates and returns a new NSManagedObjectContext that is configured as you want and then you call this method whenever you need to do something on another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code creates an `NSPersistentContainer`, then gets the `viewContext` from the container. The container can also create other contexts, if you want. You can either call `container.newBackgroundContext()` to create a new context like the one you describe (it will use private queue concurrency). You can also use `context.performBackgroundTask(_:)` to have the container create a new private-queue context on the fly for some background work.